# Kinect coordinates new SDK

Tags: kinect

I can not find this method in the new microsoft kinect sdk
`nui.SkeletonEngine.DepthImageToSkeleton`

Can someone please some indications on how to accomplish this?

[Microsoft Kinect SDK depth data to real world coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796670/microsoft-kinect-sdk-depth-data-to-real-world-coordinates)

in the new Microsoft Kinect SDK?

Answer (score 5):

The method has changed to `SkeletonPoint DepthImageFrame.MapToSkeletonPoint(int depthX, int depthY)`.  Like everything else in the new SDK, its located in the *Microsoft.Kinect* namespace.

Given a **DepthImageFrame**:

```
SkeletonPoint point = depthImageFrame.MapToSkeletonPoint(depthX, depthY);
```

A lot has changed with the new release.  A list of API changes can be found here: http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/k4w-details-of-api-changes-from-beta2-to-v1-managed/#namespacesAssemblyName